# Best practice to handle undefined variables dynamicaly in JavaScript/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, try-catch

Ok, maybe is not the best title, but I lacked inspiration, so here goes:

Let's say you have a "global" (not really) variable to store temporary data and sub data as random users interact with your server. Normally on the first interaction with your server, the main variable will be undefined so you need to handle that case.

Now, what puzzled me about this, is what's the best practice performance wise to do this if there are a lot of users and **a lot** way more interactions with the variable.

Puzzled?  Yeah, I know, words are not my strong point so let me show you in code

So you have

```
var user_data = [];
```

Then a function that handles user interaction to store data

```
function writeData(uid, data_name, data)
```

Now, on first interaction, user_data[uid][data_name] is undefined, and so it's user_data[uid]

I know you can handle this 2 ways:

*With if* -

```
if(!user_data[uid]) user_data[uid] = {}
 user_data[uid][data_name] = data
```

*With try/catch*

```
try{user_data[uid][data_name] = data} 
catch(e) {user_data[uid] = {}; writeData(uid, data_name, data)}
```

The if will check on every interaction, and like I said there are a lot.
Try catch will trigger once, but it has a cost as a block (afaik)

Which one is better? Or is there a another better way

Comment: Don´t check by falsy value, check if it is defined already with hasOwnProperty or === undefined

Comment: May I ask why? Is it better performance wise?  (not trying to be sarcastic, these are legit questions)

Comment: If you know that user_data[uid] is always either undefined or {} its fine, but if user_data[uid] was set to a falsy value such as 0, doing if(!user_data[uid]) does not really check if it is already defined or not.

Comment: Ah ok, you're right, but in this case is always an object. Thanks for the input :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had to rewrite the test because it doesn't work fine in the Snippet

So I made this for node.js:

```js
var present = require('present');


    function test(val,ud,fun) {
      
       var k = 10000000;
       
       var t = present();
       
        for(var i=0; i<k;i++)
        {
          var uid = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
          fun(uid,ud,"value");
        }
        
        var tf = present()-t;
        console.log("END "+val+" at "+tf);

        return tf;
        
        }

    function setValue_Opp(uid,ud,value)
        {
        (ud[uid] || (ud[uid] = {})) && (ud[uid].value = value);

        }
        
    function setValue_Try(uid,ud,value)
        {
        try{ ud[uid].value = value}
        catch(e){ ud[uid] = {}; setValue_Try(uid,ud,value)};

        }
        
    function setValue_Cond(uid,ud,value)
        {
       if(!ud[uid]) ud[uid] = {}
       
       ud[uid].value = value;

        }


var k1=0;
var k2=0;
var k3=0;

    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

    k1+=test(1,{}, setValue_Cond);
    k2+=test(2,{}, setValue_Try);
    k3+=test(3,{}, setValue_Opp);
    }

console.log(k1,k2,k3)
```

And in the end:
3244.328997004777 3695.0267750024796 3437.6855720058084

Which means:

<s>**The best is the classical if**</s>

The second best is condintional operators method

And the worst is the try-catch

So it seems the classics win

Edited:

With further tests thanks to [@CRayen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3060210/crayen) the best method is :

```
 (!ud[uid] && (ud[uid] = {})) && (ud[uid].value = value);
```

Comment: The above might not be right. To prove it I tried the same code with changing the order of function call like below
    test(3,setValue_Opp);
    test(1,setValue_Try);
    test(2,setValue_Cond);

And the reult is :

END 3 at 3685.9000000040396 |||| END 1 at 4307.0000000006985  |||  END 2 at 3659.700000003795

Answer (score 1):

I feel we can take advantage of ES6 ternaries as below:

```js
let user_data = {}
const writeData = (uid, data_name, data) => {

((user_data[uid] || (user_data[uid] = {}))  && (user_data[uid][data_name] = data ))
console.log(user_data)
// perform write action
}

writeData('1',"test","test1");
writeData('2',"test","test2");
writeData('1',"test","test3");
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't knew || acts like this so it halts if true. Thanks, will definitely use this in my code. But the question remains, is this better or with try catch? (performance wise, because this it does look pretty)

Comment: I would recommend ternary approach than `try/catch`

Answer (score 1):

@Nertan , 
There is a partiality in your proof :P . I have slightly tweeked the ternary way (same as the order of execution in if way). With this you can conclude.

```js
//var present = require('present');


    function test(val,ud,fun) {
      
       var k = 10000000;
       
       var t = Date.now();
       
        for(var i=0; i<k;i++)
        {
          var uid = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
          fun(uid,ud,"value");
        }
        
        var tf = Date.now()-t;

        return tf;
        
        }

    function setValue_Opp(uid,ud,value)
        {
        (!ud[uid] && (ud[uid] = {})) && (ud[uid].value = value);

        }
        
    function setValue_Try(uid,ud,value)
        {
        try{ ud[uid].value = value}
        catch(e){ ud[uid] = {}; setValue_Try(uid,ud,value)};

        }
        
    function setValue_Cond(uid,ud,value)
        {
       if(!ud[uid]) ud[uid] = {}
       
       ud[uid].value = value;

        }


var k1=0;
var k2=0;
var k3=0;

    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

    k1+=test(1,{}, setValue_Cond);
    k2+=test(2,{}, setValue_Try);
    k3+=test(3,{}, setValue_Opp);
    }

console.log(k1,k2,k3)
```

Comment: You are right, "ternary" is faster, but I just copied the one from you answer earlier :)